# Printer prints perfect horizontal white lines

Tags: printing

Printer prints perfect white lines when printing full colors, but prints fine when printing lighter colors.

It does not appear to be anything mechanical (nozzle, drum, or pull mechanisms).

Is it a driver or configuration issue?

Canon MP560 (inkjet)

Here is scan of a test print page:

[image]

Here are three solid rectangles printed from MSPaint, see how all colors have the same defect? Which means that problem isn't clogged nozzles.
[image: Three solid rectangles]

Comment: I think rather than "prints perfect white lines", it's skipping a small line-feed form your printer and is lacking ink and not printing white. If not a line-feed problem, then perhaps a problem with ink coming out of the dark section. It's going to be a trouble shoot. Try replacing the ink cartridge(s) first and go from there.

Comment: You printer should have a "clean the print head" option to correct this

Comment: See 3 blue stripes at the top? First is striped, but two below it (also blue, but lighter) print fine. If it would be a clogged head - why would it be clogged for intense blue, but works fine for a lighter blue (lower saturation)?

Comment: Also, black stripe (and two others) don't have gaps - so it can't be line feed problem.

Comment: You might want to contact Canon tech support.  They may already be familiar with what could cause this and have a solution.